# Observable (Rx) for a continuous (async) stream of objects in repository

Tags: c#, asynchronous, repository, system.reactive

I got a `Repository` of type `Item` My goal is to have the `Repository` provide an `Observable` or basically a "stream" of `Item` using an Observable.

I'm a complete beginner regarding RX but think I got a good grasp of the basics. My problem has been finding a way to keep an `Observable` alive and manually push `Item` to it as they come in (which might be sockets or anything else async based). Basically a Hot Observable.

I got it working using a `Subject<Item>` to which I subscribe but I'm missing the power of a "regular Observable", i.e. LINQ queries to filter the stream. I'm afraid that I'm overlooking something or looked past a fitting approach.

Any insight or direction for a beginner like me would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing a `using System.Reactive.Linq` reference, otherwise Select et. al. should show up on the `Subject<T>`.

Comment: My reading of his question was that he has it working for `Subject`, but not for `IObservable`.

Comment: This was exactly it. I was stumped why I didn't have the LINQ operators on Subject and more why I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc47

> Make your class native to IObservable
>
> If you are about to build new system, you could consider using just
>   IObservable.
>
> Use Subject as backend for IObservable
>
> ```
> class UseSubject
> {
>     public class Order
>     {            
>         private DateTime? _paidDate;
>
>         private readonly Subject<Order> _paidSubj = new Subject<Order>();
>         public IObservable<Order> Paid { get { return _paidSubj.AsObservable(); } }
>
>         public void MarkPaid(DateTime paidDate)
>         {
>             _paidDate = paidDate;                
>             _paidSubj.OnNext(this); // Raise PAID event
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static void Main()
>     {
>         var order = new Order();
>         order.Paid.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Paid")); // Subscribe
>
>         order.MarkPaid(DateTime.Now);
>     }
> }
> ```